# Transitioning from the Obsolete FragementManager to Android.Support.V4.App

Tags: c#, android, android-fragments, android-dialogfragment

I have several `DialogFragement`'s in my app that I need to transition to `Android.Support.V4.App.DialogFragment` so my app is compatible with API 29 (Q).  I began by converting my "Change Password" dialog fragment code to this:

```
class ChangePassword : Android.Support.V4.App.DialogFragment 
{
    public event DialogEventHandler Dismissed;
    public string selection = "";
    private int error = 0;
    public User MyUser;

    public override View OnCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        base.OnCreateView(inflater, container, savedInstanceState);
        View view = inflater.Inflate(Resource.Layout.ChangePassword, container, false);
        Button ok = view.FindViewById<Button>(Resource.Id.button_ok);
        EditText currentPassword = view.FindViewById<EditText>(Resource.Id.currentPassword);
        EditText newPassword1 = view.FindViewById<EditText>(Resource.Id.newPassword1);
        EditText newPassword2 = view.FindViewById<EditText>(Resource.Id.newPassword2);
        ok.Click += (sender, args) =>
        {
            if (currentPassword.Text != "" && (newPassword1.Text.ToUpper () == newPassword2.Text.ToUpper()) && (newPassword1.Text != "" || newPassword2.Text != ""))
            {
                ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Tls12;
                OMLDataInterfaceWeb.OMLDataInterface datainterface = new OMLDataInterfaceWeb.OMLDataInterface();
                try
                {
                    datainterface.ChangeUserPassword(MyUser.Username, currentPassword.Text, newPassword1.Text);
                }
                catch (Exception e)
                {
                    error = 1;
                    Utils.showMessage(e.Message, "Error");
                }

                if (error == 0)
                {
                    selection = newPassword2.Text;
                    if (null != Dismissed)
                        Dismissed(this, new DialogEventArgs { Selection = selection });
                }
            }
            else
            {
                if (currentPassword.Text == "")
                {
                    // Android.Content.Context context = new AppContext() ;
                    Utils.showMessage("Enter the current password.","ERROR");
                }
                else
                {
                    if (newPassword1.Text == "")
                    {
                        Utils.showMessage("The first new password field is blank.", "ERROR");
                    } else if (newPassword2.Text == "")
                    {
                        Utils.showMessage("Please re-enter the new password.", "ERROR");

                    } else if (newPassword1.Text.ToUpper() != newPassword2.Text.ToUpper())
                    {
                        Utils.showMessage("The passwords do not match.", "ERROR");
                    }
                }
            }
        };

        return view;
    }
    public override void OnResume()
    {
        int width = 900; 
        int height = 900;
        Dialog.Window.SetLayout(width, height);
        base.OnResume();
    }
}
```

Note that I'm using `Android.Support.V4.App.DialogFragment` as opposed to the `Android.App.DialogFragment`.

I call this from another activity with a button click, that code is:

```
        btnChangePassword.Click += (sender, e) =>
        {
            Android.Support.V4.App.FragmentTransaction transcation = FragmentManager; //FragmentManager;    // FragmentManager.BeginTransaction();
            ChangePassword changePassword = new ChangePassword();
            changePassword.MyUser = MyUser;
            changePassword.Show(transcation, "Dialog");

            changePassword.Dismissed += (s, a) => {
                /* do something with e.Selection here */

                if (a.Selection.ToUpper() != "")
                {
                    ChangePassword _exportFragment = (ChangePassword)FragmentManager.FindFragmentByTag("Dialog");
                    if (_exportFragment != null)
                    {
                        _exportFragment.Dismiss();
                    }
                    changedPassword = true;
                   thePassword = a.Selection;
                }
                else
                {
                    Toast.MakeText(this, "Enter new password.", ToastLength.Long).Show();
                }
            };

        };
```

I'm getting two errors in the button click code, the first is `Cannot implicitly convert type 'Android.App.FragmentManager' to 'Android.Support.V4.App.FragmentTransaction` which occurs on this line of code `Android.Support.V4.App.FragmentTransaction transcation = FragmentManager;`, assuming that I also had to qualify `FragmentManager` with `Android.Support.V4.App.`, I changed the code to read `Android.Support.V4.App.FragmentTransaction transcation = Android.Support.V4.App.FragmentManager;`, this generated the error `'FragmentManager' is a type, which is not valid in the given context`, the other error Im getting is `Cannot convert type 'Android.App.Fragment' to 'MyAndroidApp.ChangePassword'` which occurs on the line `ChangePassword _exportFragment = (ChangePassword)FragmentManager.FindFragmentByTag("Dialog");`.  I've searched all ove for an answer and nothing I've tried has resolved this.  What am I missing?

Comment: Among other problems, your capitalization doesn't match the correct capitalization (all the package names should be lowercase), a FragmentManager is different than a FragmentTransaction, and you should _really_ convert to the `androidx` version instead: https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/releases/fragment.  support.v4 is outdated and unmaintained.

Comment: If, by package names, you mean `Android.Support.V4.App`, that's not true for Visual Studio 2019.  Perhaps I should have indicated my development platform.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to figure it out.  The new button click code is:

```
        btnChangePassword.Click += (sender, e) =>
        {

            Android.Support.V4.App.FragmentTransaction transcation = SupportFragmentManager.BeginTransaction();
            ChangePassword changePassword = new ChangePassword();
            changePassword.MyUser = MyUser;
            changePassword.Show(transcation, "Dialog");

            changePassword.Dismissed += (s, a) => {
                /* do something with e.Selection here */

                if (a.Selection.ToUpper() != "")
                {
                    ChangePassword _exportFragment = (ChangePassword)SupportFragmentManager.FindFragmentByTag("Dialog");
                    if (_exportFragment != null)
                    {
                        _exportFragment.Dismiss();
                    }
                    changedPassword = true;
                   thePassword = a.Selection;
                }
                else
                {
                    Toast.MakeText(this, "Enter new password.", ToastLength.Long).Show();
                }
            };
```